# Sitecore Media Framework Brightcove Upgrade Error

Tags: media-library, upgrade, brightcove

We recently upgraded our Sitecore installation from 8.0 Update 7 to 8.2 Update 4. As part of the upgrade, we needed to get a new version of the Media Framework and Brightcove plugin.

The Media Framework was upgraded from 2.1 to 2.2 using the upgrade package provided via SDN. This package appears to have worked fine in upgrading the existing YouTube connection accounts in the Media Framework.

Next, the Brightcove plugin was upgraded from version 2.1 rev. 150323 to 3.0. The new package was installed, files were specified to overwrite existing files, Sitecore items were specified to override existing items as per the installation instructions on the Brightcove site. The post-installation instructions were then followed.

Now, when "Import All" is run on the Brightcove account the import immediately is cut short and the following errors can be found in the Sitecore log files:

```
18812 09:04:25 WARN  WebUtil.QueryStringCache cache is cleared by Sitecore.Caching.Generics.Cache`1+DefaultScavengeStrategy[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] strategy. Cache running size was 18 KB.
ManagedPoolThread #8 09:04:36 INFO  Job started: Import MediaFramework Content
ManagedPoolThread #0 09:04:37 WARN  MediaFramework *** Null Result during importing Called by:TagCollectionImporter
ManagedPoolThread #0 09:04:37 ERROR MediaFramework *** Import data failed.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Http null result
Source: AgencyOasis.MediaFramework.Brightcove
   at AgencyOasis.MediaFramework.Brightcove.Import.EntityCollectionImporter`1.<GetWithPaging>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__92`1.MoveNext()
   at AgencyOasis.MediaFramework.Brightcove.Import.TagCollectionImporter.<ReadAllTags>d__1.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.MediaFramework.Pipelines.MediaSyncImport.CallItemImport.Process(MediaSyncImportArgs args)

ManagedPoolThread #7 09:04:37 WARN  MediaFramework *** Null Result during importing Called by:VideoCollectionImporter
ManagedPoolThread #7 09:04:37 ERROR MediaFramework *** Import data failed.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Http null result
Source: AgencyOasis.MediaFramework.Brightcove
   at AgencyOasis.MediaFramework.Brightcove.Import.EntityCollectionImporter`1.<GetWithPaging>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.MediaFramework.Pipelines.MediaSyncImport.CallItemImport.Process(MediaSyncImportArgs args)

ManagedPoolThread #5 09:04:38 WARN  MediaFramework *** Null Result during importing Called by:PlayListCollectionImporter
ManagedPoolThread #5 09:04:38 ERROR MediaFramework *** Import data failed.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Http null result
Source: AgencyOasis.MediaFramework.Brightcove
   at AgencyOasis.MediaFramework.Brightcove.Import.EntityCollectionImporter`1.<GetWithPaging>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.MediaFramework.Pipelines.MediaSyncImport.CallItemImport.Process(MediaSyncImportArgs args)

ManagedPoolThread #8 09:04:38 INFO  Job ended: Import MediaFramework Content (units processed: )
```

Any ideas as to what might be going on here? My next step was going to be generating .pdb files for the Brightcove .dlls and trying to step through and see what's going on there but I wanted to reach out here first in case anyone has experienced something similar before.

Comment: Can you check whether during upgrading credentials for Brightcove were not cleaned up?

Comment: The existing values are still there, however I've noticed that the field names have changed from Read Token/Write Token to Client ID/Client Secret. Maybe these are different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like this version of the Brighcove plugin uses a different back-end API and you have to create an authorized application. Replacing the existing Read/Write Tokens with a newly generated Client ID/Client Secret did the trick. A guide to generating the credentials can be found at:

https://support.brightcove.com/getting-started-brightcove-video-connect-sitecore-experience-platform#contents